# SSH does not allow the use of a key with group readable permissions

Tags: linux, ssh, git, private-key, deployment

*I have a development git server that deploys to a live server when the `live` branch is pushed to.
Every user has their own login and therefore the `post-receive` hook which does the live deployment is run under their own user.*

*Because I don't want to have to maintain the users public keys as authorized keys on the remote live server I have made up a set of keys that 'belong's to the git system to add to remote live servers (In the `post-receive` hook I am using `$GIT_SSH` to set the private key with the `-i` option).*

My problem is that because of all the users might want to deploy to live, the git system's private key has to be at least group readable and SSH really doesn't like this.

Here's a sample of the error:

```
XXXX@XXXX /srv/git/identity % ssh -i id_rsa XXXXX@XXXXX
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0640 for 'id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: id_rsa
```

I've looked around expecting to find something in the way of forcing ssh to just go through with the connection but I've found nothing but people blindly saying that you just shouldn't allow access to anything but a single user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a nice simple and secure way.

Create a new user for the ssh transfer, I'll call it git-sync.  Create a similar user on the server with group membership for the git repository.  Add the public key for sync-user into that users authorized_keys2 file.  I'm assuming the git users are all members of the gitgroup.  Make sure the git-sync user is also a member of this group.

Now edit your /etc/sudoers file to include a line like:

```
%gitgroup ALL=(git-sync) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git
```

This will allow any member of the gitgroup group to run the command /usr/bin/bit as git-sync without a password.

Now put something like this in your post-receive hook:

```
sudo -u git-sync /usr/bin/git push origin
```

Comment: This is better than what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You *CAN* use group readable identity files, UNLESS you're the owner of the key.
So, just set the identity file to be owned by, for example, the root user and then
all your git repository users are set to go.

A nice benefit to this is that you don't need sudo - the solution will be more simple.

Note that this will run into the original problem again if you're using root to push to your git repo.

Comment: This is awesome, and much better than the "don't do that" answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Permissions 0640 for 'id_rsa' are too open.
```

The private key must remain private. You shouldn't allow anyone to read it.

> *Because I don't want to have to maintain the users public keys as authorized keys on the remote live server I have made up a set of keys
>   that 'belong's to the git system to add to remote live servers (In the
>   `post-receive` hook I am using `$GIT_SSH` to set the private key with
>   the `-i` option).*

1. setup a key pair to ssh from the dev to the production server
2. in the `post-receive` hook script, try something like this:

   ```
   if [ "live" == "$branch" ]; then
       ssh -t user@prod "git --work-tree=... --git-dir=... checkout -f"
   fi
   ```

Comment: How can I "setup a key pair to ssh from the dev to the production server", this is what I am having a problem with.

I already have 2 in place.

Comment: On the dev: `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-copy-id user@prod`. On the prod: `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`, `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: The problem is that there are multple users, therefore I have to repeat that for every user that wants to edit times by every project that exists on the server.

Comment: No. You only need to setup only two more users: one to ssh from the dev to the prod, and another to run the `git checkout...` (on the prod).

Comment: The `post-receive` hook (dev machine) is run by the user that is pushing a change (therefore under the users permission) so they will all have different keys, I can't help which user it will be. There are two `post-receive` hooks on two different servers in action.

Comment: If you don't want to spend a lot of time fixing public keys on the server, how about just giving the same private key to every user and letting them set it up in their own .ssh directory?

Comment: @scjr: I mean the `post-receive` hook script on the dev server.